# Getting UIWebView initial page request's HTML response

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to get the result of the initial page request's HTML response
received in UIWebView, and block any  tags and replace them with dog photos.

I want to get the HTML before it sends off additional requests for the images, css, javascript embeded in the HTML(which I can get the individual request URLs with `NSURLProtocol`.

My idea is to somehow get the `<img>` tags, then replace the `src` attribute with my dog photos stored locally, before it actually sends out the request for the original images.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `HTML` content using `Javascript` with the following methods

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
```

One option is to use pure `Javascript` create a `replaceTags` function

```
[[self webView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"replaceTags();"];
```

or get the html content and manipulate and replace the tags in the `WebViewController` using `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement`

```
NSString *htmlString = [[self webView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

And load again the content

```
[[self webView] loadHTMLString:updatedHtmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't that fire off a request? I want to replace the image tags before the server-intended images are loaded.

Comment: If you use the second approach it will of course fire a second request, but if you manipulate your response in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` it won't fire a second request here are some [examples](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring)